# Separate bottom navigation bar widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am new to Flutter. I separate my bottom navigation bar file and call it in my screen file. Basically, I want to do some background color like container on selected icon. This is my code and design that I want it to be like this.

[image]

```
BottomNavigationBar bottom_navbar_home(
   

){  

   return BottomNavigationBar( 
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
              items: [
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                  
                  icon: Icon(Icons.home_filled,), label: 'Home'),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.feed_outlined), label: 'Activity'),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.account_balance_wallet_outlined),
                    label: 'Wallet'),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.chat_bubble_outline),
                    label: 'Notification'),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.person), label: 'Settings'),
              ],

   );

   
}
```

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BottomNavigationBarItem/backgroundColor.html
check these out

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve something close to this by using the Material you navigation bar widget.

```
return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Demo'),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBarTheme(
          data: NavigationBarThemeData(
            indicatorColor: Colors.grey.shade900,
          ),
          child: NavigationBar(
            destinations: const [
              NavigationDestination(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.home_filled,
                ),
                label: 'Home',
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined, color: Colors.white,),
              ),
              NavigationDestination(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.feed,
                ),
                label: 'Activity',
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.feed_outlined, color: Colors.white,),
              ),
              NavigationDestination(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.account_balance_wallet,
                ),
                label: 'Wallet',
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.account_balance_wallet_outlined, color: Colors.white,),
              ),
              NavigationDestination(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.chat_bubble,
                ),
                label: 'Notification',
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.chat_bubble_outline, color: Colors.white,),
              ),
              NavigationDestination(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.person,
                ),
                label: 'Settings',
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.person_outline, color: Colors.white,),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
    );
```

[image]

Comment: the NavigationBarTheme saved my day. thank you